# make, write a rule for single file

Tags: makefile

I need a file to have a dedicated rule for use special flags.
Now I use

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OE): special_file.c
    $(ECHO) "Compiling file $< => $@" 
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_SPECIAL) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OE): %.c $(OBJDIR)
    $(ECHO) "Compiling file $< => $@" 
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

But isn't working for special_file.c. It seems the path is not known, but when I comment my special rule and let make all files, file is compiling fine.

How to divert make to a rule just for one file?

Thanks very much in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [Target-specific Variable Values](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific):

```
$(OBJDIR)/special_file.$(OE): CFLAGS += --specific_flags
$(OBJDIR)/special_file.$(OE): special_file.c

$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OE): %.c $(OBJDIR)
    $(ECHO) "Compiling file $< => $@" 
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but this way my -include passed to CFLAGS will be evaluated before -I includes with a lot of errors. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: You can make a INCLUDE variable, and change it target-specificly (like with CFLAG, using = instead of +=). I think it will do what you want.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just += to last INCLUDE a SPECIAL_INCLUDE and works very well.

Comment: Note you don't need the explicit prerequisite line, `$(OBJDIR)/special_file.$(OE): special_file.c`.  That's already implied by the pattern rule.

Comment: See below for a philosophical concern with target-specific variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it this way, you'll have to write it as a static rule:

```
$(OBJDIR)/special_file.$(OE): special_file.c
        $(ECHO) "Compiling file $< => $@" 
        $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS_SPECIAL) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

However, much simpler and more flexible is to use recursive variable naming.  Do something like this:

```
special_file_FLAGS = $(CFLAGS_SPECIAL)

$(OBJDIR)/%.$(OE): %.c
        $(ECHO) "Compiling file $< => $@" 
        $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $($*_FLAGS) $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDE) $< -o $@
```

The automatic variable `$*` expands to the stem (the part that matches `%`).  Now when you build anything other than `special_file.c`, say `other_file.c`, make will expand `$(other_file_FLAGS)` which is empty.  When you build `special_file.c`, make will expand `$(special_file_FLAGS)`.

BTW, you should (almost) *never* list a directory as a prerequisite of a target.  Search for other answers to find out why not and the right way to ensure the target directory is created.

ETA:

Target-specific variables are definitely a cool feature.  I tend to not use them, though.  Why?  Because I prefer to separate my *data* from my *rules*.

If you use target-specific variables, you are mixing together the rule syntax (the target) with the data syntax (the variable assignment).  Using the recursive variable name method, I keep the rule syntax and the data assignment separate.  What if I decide I need to change my pattern rule so that the target name changes?  With target-specific variables I have to go through all my files and change the target names.  With recursive variable naming, I just change the pattern rule and it Just Works.

In my build environments I typically have makefiles containing only data (variable assignments), plus an `include` of a common makefile that declares all my rules.  Avoiding the need to leak target formatting syntax all over my general data-driven makefiles, escaping from my uber-magical common rule definitions, keeps me from doing much with target-specific variables.

Comment: Thanks also for suggestions.